# How to iterate over rows and assign values to a new column

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I have a dataframe with over 75k rows, having about 13 pre-existing columns. Now, I want to create a new column based on an `if` statement, such that:

if each row of a certain column has the same value as the next, then the value in the new column for that row would be 0 or 1.

The `if` statement checks for two equalities (columns are `tags_list` and `gateway_id`).

The below code snippet is what I have tried

```
for i in range(1,len(df_sort['date'])-1):

    if (df_sort.iloc[i]['tags_list'] == df_sort.iloc[i+1]['tags_list']) & (df_sort.iloc[i]['gateway_id'] == df_sort[i+1]['gateway_id']):
        df_sort.iloc[i]['Transit']=0
    else:
        df_sort.iloc[i]['Transit']=1
```

Getting a `keyerror :2` in this case

PS: All of the columns have the same number of rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (df_sort.iloc[i]['tags_list'] == df_sort.iloc[i+1]['tags_list']) & 
       (df_sort.iloc[i]['gateway_id'] == df_sort.iloc[i+1]['gateway_id']):
```

`df_sort[i+1]['gateway_id']` should be `df_sort.iloc[i+1]['gateway_id']`

Also, are you sure you want to iterate from 1 and not from 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

There is `numpy` machinery for this, namely [`numpy.diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html). Consider a DataFrame that already has some generic column 'x' populated.

```
In [48]: df['x'].values                                                         
Out[48]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3])

In [49]: df['x_diff'] = (np.diff(df['x'], prepend=0) != 0) * 1                   

In [50]: df['x_diff'].values                                                    
Out[50]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1])
```

If you need the zeros and ones flipped, just change `!=` to `==`.